# integrating iOS4 project into iOS5 project

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, storyboard, integration

I have a newbie question about integrating two iOS apps. I have created an app in iOS 5 (my first app so I dont have any knowledge of iOS 4 except the fact thah there were xibs files instead of storyboard and also ARC was not included). 
Now I have to include one older standalone app (built for iOS 4 with xibs and non ARC) to my iOS 5 app. Lets say that in my app on Main menu view there will be a new button opening the main menu of the other app.

So I did some research and find out how to disable ARC by the fno-objc-arc flag. Fine, now I have imported all the files of the second app to mine app and all the classes have the flag set.
I can still run my app without problem.

Now I have no idea how to let my new button to open the mainViewController of the old app - this app has MainWindow.xib (contains a window and one navigation controller). This MainWindow is set to be Main Interface in the old project. There are also some init call in appMainDelegate file. Where can I call them in my app?

Could anybody tell me what needs to be done. I have an idea, that I will add only one new UIViewController to my storyboard. This will be the starting point for the old app and than everything will work as it used to. Or will I have to create more controllers (for every xib) in my storyboard? This is where I dont know what to do. Any help much appriciated. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like the following, anything like it or simmular should work:

In the method of the button (the one you call your new button) have it execute the following code:

```
OldAppMainViewController *controller = [[OldAppMainViewController alloc] init];
//Here you can assign vallues to any properties that you might want to
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

That old apps main view controller should have a init with nub named function so it should work. If this does not work try something along the lines of:

```
OldAppMainViewController *controller = [[OldAppMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OldAppMainViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Where the NIB name is the .xib file name without the extension.

Also make sure that all connections in interface builder is setup correctly